# Compile and run single file c++ programs in Emacs[SOLVED]

Tags: shell-command

I want to bind to a key a compile-and-run function to be able to compile my C++ single file programs and run them into a term/shell so I could give my variables values whenever  I use `cin` in my programs.

For example, in my Neovim config, I had this line:

```
autocmd FileType cpp  nnoremap <F8> :w <CR> :vsp <CR> <C-w>l :term g++ % -o %< && ./%< <CR> i
```

I want to have something similar in Emacs.
In Emacs, this line will be looking like so:

```
(define-key c++-mode-map (kbd "<f8>") #'compileandrun)
```

But I have no clue how the `compileandrun` function will look.

edit  1:
Here is a function I have tried

```
(defun compileandrun()
  (interactive)
  (compile (concat "g++ "  (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)) " -o " (file-name-sans-extension   (file-name-nondirectory 
           (buffer-file-name)))))
   (term  (concat "./" (file-name-sans-extension
           (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))))))
```

it only compiles the program but it dosen't run it .

Comment: Please put your answer in its own post rather than include it in the question. It's fine to self-answer.

Answer (score 2):

`compile` uses the shell. You can chain program execution with `&&` like `g++ test.cc -o test && ./test`. With the last command `./test` is executed if compilation with `g++` succeeds.

I'll modify your command accordingly:

```el
(defun compileandrun()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((src (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))
         (exe (file-name-sans-extension src)))
    (compile (concat "g++ " src " -o " exe " && ./" exe))))
```

Comment: You will need to use ```let*``` form here because 'src' variable is used inside the 'exe' binding; otherwise you will get error about void variable for 'src'

Comment: @crajun Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final elisp function that works. It automatically switches to the window and move the cursor to the bottom .

```
(defun compileandrun()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (compile (concat "g++ "  (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)) " -o " (file-name-sans-extension   (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))) " && ./" (file-name-sans-extension  (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))) t )
(other-window 1)
(end-of-buffer)
) 
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "<f8>") #'compileandrun)))
```

If you have any improvments let me know .