# is there a way to make compile shell process happen in eshell / "real" shell?

Tags: shell, eshell, compile

i wanted to bind a key to a compile and run command, then i found this post, [Compile and run single file c++ programs in Emacs[SOLVED]](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54690/compile-and-run-single-file-c-programs-in-emacssolved)
( last answer)

It works perfectly fine and as intended.

The only problem i am having is: is it possible to run the "compile" process in the eshell or in the shell instead of the "compile" shell?  The problem with the "compile" shell is that i am unable to write anything after the program exited.

For those who dont want to click on the link,here is the elisp function, even tho i dont think it has much to do with the question:

````
(defun compileandrun()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (compile (concat "g++ "  (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)) " -o " (file-name-sans-extension   (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))) " && ./" (file-name-sans-extension  (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))) t )
(other-window 1)
(end-of-buffer)
) 
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "<f8>") #'compileandrun)))
    ```
````

Comment: You can compile a program in `eshell`, but you cannot use `compilation-mode` in an `eshell` buffer.  If you want the goodies of `compilation-mode`, then you'll need to stick with using the `compile.el` library.  You can continue to execute new commands with `compile` provided that you have the correct working directory, or you `let`-bind the `default-directory` for the duration of the `compile` command.  E.g, `(defun make () (interactive) (compile "make"))`; or, `M-x eval-expression RET (compile "make install") RET`.   FYI:  `eshell` is able to process Lisp expressions at the command prompt.

Comment: @lawlist There is `compilation-minor-mode` which you can temporarily activate to have the goodies of `compilation-mode`. I just wrote a little C++ test program and put intentionally an error in there. I run `g++ test.cc -o test.exe` in an Eshell and switched on `M-x compilation-minor.mode` afterwards. The errors are highlighted like in `compilation-mode` and clicking on the error lines in the Eshell buffer sends me to the occurrence of the error in the C++ file. When I am done with debugging I can switch `compilation-minor-mode` off and use the Eshell buffer as usual.